# Android App - Java: Adding to an arrayList then updating a ListView

Tags: java, android

I have coded this android app which produces a listView containing songs which are streamed from the internet, and the user can play them by clicking them using the mediaPlayer.

What i am having trouble with is allowing the user to add a song to the arrayList that populates the ListView. I have used the settings page to add textboxes so the user can add their songs by inputting, Song Name, Artist and the Direct Link to the song. Though the code i have used for this doesn't work, it should add the Song Name, Artist and Direct Link into the array_list_music ArrayList, then update the ListView, or at least i think that is how it should be done.

I have shown my code below.

So if someone could help with this problem, that would be great, thanks.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.superandroidtutorials.supermusic;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnPreparedListener, MediaController.MediaPlayerControl {

    private static final String TAG = "AudioPlayer";
    private ListView list;
    public MainArrayAdapter adapter;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private MediaController mediaController;
    private String audioFile;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    ArrayList<String> array_list_music = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = getListView();

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaController = new MediaController(this);

        //ArrayList<String> array_list_music = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Used to add a song to the array list
        array_list_music
            .add("Song Name"
                + " ### "
                + "Artist"
                + " ### "
                + "http://incoming.jazz-on-line.com/a/mp3w/1941_149.mp3");
        array_list_music
            .add("Song Name"
                + " ### "
                + "Artist"
                + " ### "
                + "http://tindeck.com/download/2dc7b728b491c2211bbe68f10785e59c/xvla/%5Btindeck.com%5D%20-%20Bob%20Acri%20-%20Sleep%20Away.mp3");
        array_list_music
            .add("Song Name"
                + " ### "
                + "Artist"
                + " ### "
                + "http://tinyurl.com/lo4j7rm");

        adapter = new MainArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, array_list_music);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        //used to display toast and to play song using the URL, when clicking on a song
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                Object item = getListView().getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                String the_list_item = item.toString();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are now listening to: " + the_list_item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String[] aux = the_list_item.split(" ### ");
                String url_to_play = aux[2];

                playAudio(url_to_play);//sends url from arraylist item to the playAudio method
            }
        });

    }

    //used to play audio using the android mediaPlayer
    private void playAudio(String url_to_play) {

        //stop & reset player
        try {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        //set the url, prepare it, and then play it
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url_to_play);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not open file " + url_to_play + ".", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_settings:

            Intent i_settings = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i_settings);

            break;

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mediaController.show();
        return false;
    }

    //used to hide media controller, stop the media player and to release the url.
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mediaController.hide();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
         return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
         mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int arg0) {
         mediaPlayer.seekTo(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
         mediaPlayer.start();
    }

     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared");
            mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(list);

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                mediaController.setEnabled(true);
                mediaController.show();

              }
            });
          }

     //------- what can you do from here -------
     // implement your own media player with buttons since this one is not behaving "smart"..
     // make next,previous buttons
     // highlight the list item on click
     // add your own server for playing music
     // anything you want :)

}
```

MainArrayAdapter.java

```
package com.superandroidtutorials.supermusic;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.superandroidtutorials.supermusic.R;

public class MainArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> data_array;

    public MainArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list_of_ids) {

        super(context, R.layout.main_list_rowlayout, list_of_ids);
        this.context = context;
        this.data_array = list_of_ids;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list_rowlayout, parent,
                false);

        TextView textView_main_row_song_name = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView_main_row_song_name);
        TextView textView_main_row_singer_name = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView_main_row_singer_name);

        try {

            String[] aux = data_array.get(position).split(" ### ");

            String song_name = aux[0];
            String artist = aux[1];
            String url = aux[2];

            textView_main_row_song_name.setText(song_name);
            textView_main_row_singer_name.setText(artist);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

SettingsActivity.java

```
package com.superandroidtutorials.supermusic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.superandroidtutorials.supermusic.R;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    public String str ="";
    String songName;
    String artist;
    String directLink;

    protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        songName = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextSongName)).toString();
        artist = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextArtist)).toString();
        directLink = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDirectLink)).toString();

    };

    public void buttonAddSongClicked(View v)
    {
       addSong(songName, artist, directLink);
    }

     private void addSong(String artist, String songName, String directLink) 
        {
         MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

            main.array_list_music
                .add( songName
                    + " ### "
                    + artist
                    + " ### "
                    + directLink);

            main.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            main.adapter = new MainArrayAdapter(main, main.array_list_music);
        }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What exactly do you want to see and what is happening?

Comment: Do you have error log that you can share with us?

Comment: by "doesn't work" I mean, when i open the settings page within the app, and enter a song name, artist, and direct link(url) and click the button 'Add Song', the song does not add to the ListView on the Main page, this is what I am having trouble in getting to work.

Comment: as for an error log, there is no error as such, just that the new details aren't added to the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter should implement [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) which uses the observer pattern. Then create a list of [DataSetObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DataSetObserver.html)s and use that, e.g.:

```
public class MainArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements ListAdapter {    

    private List<DataSetObserver> observers = new LinkedList<DataSetObserver>();

    //...

    public void setArray(ArrayList<String> data_array) {
        this.data_array = data_array;
        for (DataSetObserver observer : observers) {
            observer.onChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver dataSetObserver) {
        ((LinkedList) observers).addFirst(dataSetObserver);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver dataSetObserver) {
        observers.remove(dataSetObserver);
    }
}
```

**Update:** To include this into your application, you will have to change both the `MainActivity` and the `SettingsActivity` as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnPreparedListener, MediaController.MediaPlayerControl {

    // ...
    private static MainArrayAdapter adapter;
    private static ArrayList<String> array_list_music = new ArrayList<String>();

    // ...

    static void addSong(String song)
    {
        MainActivity.array_list_music.add(song);
        adapter.setArray(array_list_music);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    // ...

    private void addSong(String artist, String songName, String directLink) 
    {
        MainActivity.addSong(songName
                + " ### "
                + artist
                + " ### "
                + directLink);
    }
}
```

To explain:

- You can't create a new instance of `MainActivity` every time you want to update the list; it will be a new list every time. Making `array_list_music` static will ensure you don't have to do this.
- Accessing `array_list_music` directly will force you to implement the same code over and over again. The `MainActivity#addSong` method capsulates this behavior and, as it is static, doesn't depend on an instance of `MainActivity`.
- In `addSong` we use the method implemented in `MainArrayAdapter` that will notify all listeners of an update; that way the list will be redrawn.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, so I have entered the code which you provided, i dont quite understand it though, can you explain? does this data_array replace the array_list_music?

Comment: This is the adapter, so it is responsible for telling the list what it should display. Every time you want to change the data in the list, call the `setArray(ArrayList<String>)` function with the `array_list_music` (which is in `MainActivity`, not in `MainArrayAdapter`). Then it should automatically reload the list with the new data.

Comment: okay, could you show me the code i would need to use in my SettingsActivity, for the addSong and buttonAddSongClicked methods? so that the details entered into the EditTexts will be added to the array and listView?

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect the changes you need for the `addSong` method. Make sure you understand, why I changed the things I changed, they are quite basic problems that will cause problems in many applications you develop if you don't. Also, never make a field non-private if you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks a lot! New to android programming, but I understand now, why you have changed/added these pieces of code. Thanks again. Jason.